# Subgroup of $S_8$ generated by $(1423)(5867)$ and $(1728)(3546)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

Let $H$ be the subgroup of the symmetric group $\mathcal{S}_{8}$ generated by the permutations $a=(1423)(5867)$ and $b=(1728)(3546)$.

How can I identify $H$?

Comment: An idea: try some products in either other between $\;a,b\;$ , say $\;ab, ba, aba^2, b^{-1}ab\;$ etc.

Comment: Show your working so far. It'll both help you and encourage us to help you.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Maths.SE. It will improve the reception of your questions if you make their titles as informative as possible. I hope you agree that my revised title is more useful for other users than *How can I identify $H$?*, which just begs "What is $H$?". For more information on choosing a good title, see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144).

Comment: Did you notice that both $a$ and $b$ preserve the partition $\{1,2\}\cup\{3,4\}\cup\{5,6\}\cup\{7,8\}$? Hence so will all the elements of $H$. Also both $a^2$ and $b^2$ simply swap all these pairs (and are thus equal). I think building from this goes a long way ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elementary method which should work in this particular case.

First list all the elements of $H$ and find some useful relations among them. Fortunately, $|H|$ is not too large. You should also check whether $H$ is commutative or not. Then you could look at wikipedia to find out the list of all groups of order $|H|$. There are still several of them, but it is a good opportunity to learn about these groups. Then you should be able to recognize your group and solve your problem.